# Passing row specific data to expandableRowsComponent

Tags: reactjs, react-data-table-component

I have created a Table using react-data-table-component and now I would like to make the table rows expandable such that when I expand a row it displays details specific to that row something exactly like [Material-UI Collapsible](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#collapsible-table).

I read the react-data-table-component API documentation and its possible to have expandable rows by setting expandableRows to true and assigning a component to expandableRowsComponent. But how can I pass data to expandableRowsComponent such that if I expand row 1 I get data lets say "This is row 1", for row 2 I'll get "This is row 2" and so on...

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I went through the react-data-table-component author's github code and under stories I was able to find the relevant code which helped in figuring out exactly what I was looking for!
In case someone is interested here's the example code link: [DataTable](https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component/tree/6d75686c287551742d6d327e86a82d22daa97228/stories/DataTable)

Answer (score 0):

Data object will be automatically passed in props for each row.

for example:

```
<DataTable data={yourData} columns={yourColumns} expandableRows={true} keyField="yourId" expandableRowsComponent={ExpandableComponent} />
```

and your expandable component will receive row data inside the prop

```
const ExpandableComponent = props => <div>{props?.data?.title}</div>
```